# Coelom - Bilateria

Tags: zoology

Coelom is formed of mesoderm. all bilaterians are triplopblastic meaning they have mesoderm. does this mean that ALL of the bilaterians have a coelom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The coelom has been lost multiple times (for example, in Nematodes). Many parasitic bilaterians also lack a coelom, likely due to secondary loss.